# Stopping or pausing autoscroll function on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am working on a carousel [here](http://jsfiddle.net/S83Tp/2/) and I added a autoscroll function:

```
// auto scroll
setInterval(function() {
aux.navigate( 1, $el, $wrapper, settings, cache );
},2000);
```

Unfortunatly it keeps scrolling... How do I pause or stop the autoscroll when hovering over the items to be able to click the 'more' button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a variable on mouseover of each items and then use this variable to check inside `navigate` method before you animate and slide the items. If the mouse is on the items then just return from `navigate` method without doing anything.

```
var mouseOnItem = false;

$('.ca-item').hover(function(){
    mouseOnItem = true;
}, function(){
    mouseOnItem = false;
});

 var aux = {
    // navigates left / right
    navigate: function(dir, $el, $wrapper, opts, cache) {
        if(mouseOnItem)
            return;

        ...
        ...
    }
    ...
    ...  
  }
```

Working demo - http://jsfiddle.net/S83Tp/2/

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add a `mouseover` event listener.

First, wrap your auto scroll in a function:

```
function autoScroll() {
  var timer = '';
  clearInterval(timer);
  timer = setInterval(function() {
  aux.navigate( 1, $el, $wrapper, settings, cache );
  },2000);
}
```

Next, add an event listener to handle the hover:

```
window.addEventListener('mouseover', autoScroll, false);
```

Of course, you'll need to determine which element needs to be mouseovered, as it will most likely not be the `window` object.

Make sure you call `clearInterval(timer)` at the top of the function.